# Failing to write text file with utf8 characters

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, file, text

I am trying to save a text file which contains characters like `áàã` etc. However, I am currently failing, and can't make it work with what I've seen on the internet.

My current code is:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import codecs
import json

test_dict = {'name': [u'Joe', u'Doe'], 'id': u'1:2:3', 'description': u'he w\xe1','fav': [1, 2]}
final_text = line = "- " + json.dumps(test_dict) + "\n"

filename = 'C:\Users\PLUX\Desktop\data.txt'
f = codecs.open(filename,'w','utf8')
f.write(line)
```

which outputs:

```
- {"description": "he w\u00e1", "fav": [1, 2], "name": ["Joe", "Doe"], "id": "1:2:3"}
```

I would like it to output:

```
- {"description": "he wá", "fav": [1, 2], "name": ["Joe", "Doe"], "id": "1:2:3"}
```

Can please anyone help me?

Comment: If you can use Python 3

Comment: Unfortuantely not. I can only use Python 2.7. Many thanks for your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\u00e1` is the unicode-escaped version of the character.  The json module will convert it back to the expected representation when the data is loaded.

If you really want the unecaped version in your file, pass `ensure_ascii=False` to `json.dumps`:

```
>>> print json.dumps(test_dict, ensure_ascii=False)
{"description": "he wá", "fav": [1, 2], "name": ["Joe", "Doe"], "id": "1:2:3"}
```

To write to the file, do this:

```
>>> final_text = u'- ' + json.dumps(test_dict, ensure_ascii=False) + u'\n'
>>> with io.open('foo.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
...     f.write(final_text)
```

Note I've explicitly marked the strings that are being concatenated as unicode as I don't want Python 2 to "helpfully" convert the result to a bytestring.